# How can I implement a document Viewer which can show both PDF and Word files in Grails

Tags: grails, documentviewer

I want to implement a document viewer inside my Grails application in which I need to show PDF, Word or Excel files. Is it possible to show all these files using a single document viewer or I have to implement separate viewer for each files?. Can I achieve this using google docs?

Comment: You can this http://elfinder.org/

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?